# Maximum Principle for Nonlinear Heat Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

For a function $f(x,t)$ I'm aware of a fairly strong result about the PDE:

$\sigma^2 f_{xx} + f_t = 0,$

$f(x,0) = h(x)$,

which guarantees that any local maxima of $f$ or any of its derivatives in $x$ can only exist along the boundary $t = 0$. I'm wondering if a similar result holds for a  more complicated version of the PDE:

$\sigma^2(g_{xx},g_x,g,x,t) g_{xx} + g_t = 0,$

$g(x,0) = h(x)$.

I've been able to show that any local maxima of $g$ and $g_x$ exist only along the boundary $t = 0$ but I am having trouble with $g_{xx}$.

I'm wondering whether or not the maximum principle can be extended this far, and if so what conditions I would need on the function $\sigma$ to make it work.

Comment: Have you derived the differential equations satisfied by $u_x$, $u_{xx}$ etc. and isolated the general form, i.e. a form which is so general that all the others are but special cases, yet so specific that you can still derive a maximum principle for this general form?

Comment: Not sure if I follow your comment completely, but that sounds like the approach I've tried using. The problem is that differentiation of the PDE introduces a bunch of new terms resulting from the partial derivatives of $\sigma$. With $g_x$ the cost is minimal but with, say, $u = g_{xx}$ the PDE includes a factor with the second derivative of $\sigma^2$ in $x$ multiplying $u$ itself.

Comment: I can not promise you that it will work, but you need ignore the fact that the expressions are nasty and bundle as many terms together as you can in the effort to isolate the general form.  A small example: $u_t = a(u)u_{xx}$. Then $(u_x)_t = a(u) (u_x)_{xx} + (a'(u)u_x) (u_x)_x$. Defining $v = u_x$ we have $v_t = a(x,t) v_{xx} + b(x,t) v_x$. For the purpose of estimating $v$, the complex expression for $b$ is irrelevant, as it dies at all stationary points.

Comment: Agreed, but my understanding is that successive derivatives in $x$ do not respect this new form. For instance if we take your example one step further so that $w = v_x$, then $w_t = a(x,t) w_{xx} + b(x,t) w_x + c(x,t) w$. The inclusion of $c(x,t)w$ has been the dead end for me so far, not to mention any further derivatives which would no longer be PDEs.

Comment: I am exhausted, so I will just comment briefly. The creation term $cw$ gives exponential growth unless is is always negative in which case it does not matter. You can find maximum principles for the last form you named in Fritz John's book "Partial differential equations". When you differentiate once more, then you get the term $c_x w$ but you can treat that as an inhomogenous term with respect to $w_x$! And then apply your previous maximum principle for $w$ to estimate $w_x$. Admittedly, it get nasty :)

Comment: One small question: I have never seen you equation before. It differs dramatically from the heat equation. Would you please confirm that the signs are correct and that the equations is not $u_t = \sigma^2 u_{xx}$, but $u_t = - \sigma^2 u_{xx}$. In sincerely doubt that it will make a significant difference, but there is work to be saved if you a dealing with a nonlinear heat equation.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I was working with a backwards heat equation, the one I wrote in the original post is meant to be evaluated at $t \le 0$.

Comment: I have also done some digging since your last reply. I couldn't quite understand the result of taking further derivatives as it seems like the problem term is the $c(x,t)w$ from my last reply. I have tried some numerical examples and so far what I've found is that the decay in the second derivative $g_{xx}$ from the convolution outpaces the exponential growth from the creation term. I think now what I should look for is some condition on the function $\sigma$ that guarantees this. Naively it seems that it should have to be large relative to its second derivative in $x$.

Comment: Would it then be useful (to you) to consider a nonlinear heat equation $u_t = a(x,t,u,u_x,u_{xx},\dotsc,)u_{xx}$. I think the work would be simple here, provided $a$ is positive and *bounded* away from zero, and it could be developed as an anwer to your question. But would it be possible  to "flip" results back to your case? Moreover, for your work, do you really need to entertain the possibility that $\sigma^2$ can be arbitrarily close to zero? I am at the end of my day, so my reply will be delayed. Kind regards

Comment: The time reversal shouldn't affect the results, the one I posted was mean to be considered for $t \le 0$. Either way I investigated the idea of bounding $\sigma$ away from $0$ and it looks promising. For functions like $\sigma(x) = x^2$ there is no maximum principle, but numerically at least it seems there is one for $\sigma(x) = x^2 + \epsilon$ for some reasonably small $\epsilon$.